# resetting vps root password

Tags: password, root, vps

i purchased a vps and i forgot it's server rootpassword. i'm trying to reset it via rescue mode but i'm failing at the mounting level  :

```
 root@rescue:~# mount -o rw /dev/sda1 /mnt
mount: /dev/sda1 is write-protected, mounting read-only
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?


root@rescue:~# mount -o rw /dev/sdb1 /mnt
mount: /dev/sdb1 is write-protected, mounting read-only
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

here's the output of fdisk -l :

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 365A92FB-97D5-40E3-A37D-BD3C2F9DDD86

Device          Start        End    Sectors    Size Type
/dev/sda1          40       2048       2009 1004.5K BIOS boot
/dev/sda2        4096   40962047   40957952   19.5G Linux RAID
/dev/sda3    40962048 3905974271 3865012224    1.8T Linux RAID
/dev/sda4  3905974272 3907020799    1046528    511M Linux swap

Disk /dev/sdb: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A729FAD1-4D0D-4EF0-B368-34F5CF70AAB1

Device          Start        End    Sectors    Size Type
/dev/sdb1          40       2048       2009 1004.5K BIOS boot
/dev/sdb2        4096   40962047   40957952   19.5G Linux RAID
/dev/sdb3    40962048 3905974271 3865012224    1.8T Linux RAID
/dev/sdb4  3905974272 3907020799    1046528    511M Linux swap

Disk /dev/md3: 1.8 TiB, 1978886193152 bytes, 3865012096 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk /dev/md2: 19.5 GiB, 20970405888 bytes, 40957824 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

display of df -h

root@rescue:~# df -h

```
Filesystem                          Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
aufs                                 16G  1.5M   16G   1% /
devtmpfs                             16G     0   16G   0% /dev
```

Comment: that display is in rescue mode ovh grants me a temporary root access to change the actual server root in hardrive mode,  i'm supposed to mount the hard-drive in rescue mode and passwd root the change it. but i'm stuck in mouting level

Comment: It looks like you actual system is on RAID volumes /dev/md2 and/or /dev/md3 - please [edit] your question to include information that will help us narrow down which is the filesystem root e.g. `mount | grep ^/` or `df -h`

Comment: it could be /mnt is part of root so a mount would fail then. So do you have another disk available? /boot? If so make a dir there and try to mount  it into that dir.

Comment: could you be more specific? should i ls  /root?

Comment: The commands I posted were meant to be used separately: type EITHER `mount | grep ^/` OR `df -h`

Comment: just made a dir it displayed the same errors as before

Comment: @steeldriver i see , it's done

Comment: any fallow up? :)